# XML/XSLT parsing issues in JS

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a system where parts of XML code are transformed into HTML via an XSL sheet. All the transformation is done within Javascript, yet on Chrome (and other modern browsers like FF, etc) I get a XML parsing error. I tried different validators for the same XML and no errors are reported there, even tried online XSL transformers - no issues. So maybe I can get some help from the community to point out what I am doing wrong here. (Also tried to look at how the online XSLTs are doing it, their code is obfuscated to a degree I cant mess with :D).

Please refere to the snippet for the code. A simple XML structure (stored in its own element in the page and retrieved via getElementById, same for the XSL). The BODY has an onLoad event registered to call form_loaded() JS function, which in turn calls to create_form(). So the whole HTML file actually looks like this, let me try getting it into the snippet (please ignore any legacy HTML / CSS stuff, not the point here :D):

```html
    <HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <title>Testing XSLT</title>
    </HEAD>
    <xml style="display: none;" id="XMLFormData">
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
        <FORM>
            <SECTION title="SuperSection" id="0" display="NONE">
                <NONRECURSIVE>
                    <ELEMENT>
                        <ATTRIBUTE>
                            <TYPE>
                                <![CDATA[IFT]]>
                            </TYPE>
                            <SUBTYPE>
                                <![CDATA[]]>
                            </SUBTYPE>
                            <NAME>
                                <![CDATA[DFLTF]]>
                            </NAME>
                            <DB_TYPE>
                                <![CDATA[V]]>
                            </DB_TYPE>
                            <FIELD_TEXT>
                                <![CDATA[]]>
                            </FIELD_TEXT>
                            <BOUND_DATA>
                                <![CDATA[]]>
                            </BOUND_DATA>
                            <SIZE>
                                <![CDATA[]]>
                            </SIZE>
                            <TITLE>
                                <![CDATA[SOME TEXT]]>
                            </TITLE>
                            <VALUE>
                                <![CDATA[]]>
                            </VALUE>
                            <EVENTS>
                                <![CDATA[]]>
                            </EVENTS>
                        </ATTRIBUTE>
                    </ELEMENT>
                </NONRECURSIVE>
            </SECTION>
        </FORM>
    </xml>

    <xml style="display: none;" id="XSLDefaultForm">
        <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
            <xsl:output method="html" omit-xml-declaration="yes" standalone="yes" indent="yes" media-type="text/html" />
            <xsl:template match="/FORM/SECTION">
                <html>
                <style>
                    TD.datagridHeader {
                        border-Top: "1 solid buttonhighlight";
                        border-Left: "1 solid buttonhighlight";
                        border-Right: "1 solid buttonshadow";
                        border-Bottom: "1 solid buttonshadow";
                        background-Color: "#C5DEFD";
                        font-family: "MS Sans Serif";
                        font-size: "8pt";
                        padding: "2";
                    }

                    TD.datagridField {
                        border-Top: "1 solid buttonhighlight";
                        border-Left: "1 solid buttonhighlight";
                        border-Right: "1 solid buttonshadow";
                        border-Bottom: "1 solid buttonshadow";
                        background-color: "#FFFFFF";
                        font-size: "8pt";
                        text-align: "RIGHT";
                    }

                    FIELDSET.theStyle {
                        padding: "6";
                        font-family: "MS Sans Serif";
                        font-size: "8pt";
                        width: "1000";
                    }

                    TD.emptyTD {
                        font-family: "MS Sans Serif";
                        font-size: "8pt";
                    }

                    INPUT {
                        font-family: "MS Sans Serif";
                        font-size: "8pt";
                    }

                    INPUT.fmButton {
                        font-family: "MS Sans Serif";
                        font-size: "8pt";
                        background-Color: "#C5DEFD";
                    }

                    INPUT.actionButton {
                        font-family: "MS Sans Serif";
                        font-size: "8pt";
                        background-Color: "#C5DEFD";
                        margin-bottom: "5px";
                    }

                    TD.wingdings {
                        color: white;
                        font-family: "wingdings 2";
                        font-size: 12pt;
                        width: 12;
                    }

                    TD.white {
                        color: white;
                        font-family: MS Sans Serif;
                        font-size: 12pt;
                        width: 12;
                    }

                    SELECT.multiSelect {
                        font-family: MS Sans Serif;
                        font-size: 8pt;
                        width: 180
                    }

                    SELECT {
                        border-top: "1 none buttonhighlight";
                        border-left: "1 none buttonhighlight";
                        border-right: "1 none buttonshadow";
                        border-bottom: "1 none buttonshadow";
                    }
                </style>

                <body bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
                    <xsl:if test="@display='NORMAL'">
                        <xsl:call-template name="CREATE-NORMAL" />
                    </xsl:if>
                </body>
                </html>
            </xsl:template>

            <xsl:template name="CREATE-NORMAL">
            <fieldset class="theStyle">
                <legend style="font-weight:bold">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@title" />
                </legend>
                <br />
                <xsl:for-each select="child::*">
                    <xsl:if test="name()='NONRECURSIVE'">
                        <xsl:variable name="hidden-elements" select="*[ATTRIBUTE/SUBTYPE[text()='HIDDEN']]" />

                        <xsl:for-each select="$hidden-elements">
                            <xsl:call-template name="CREATE-ELEMENT">
                                <xsl:with-param name="add-field-text" select="1" />
                            </xsl:call-template>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </xsl:if>

                    <xsl:if test="name()='RECURSIVE'">
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </fieldset>

            <xsl:for-each select="child::*">
                <xsl:if test="name()='NONRECURSIVE'">
                    <xsl:variable name="number-of-multi-select-elements"
                        select="count(*[ATTRIBUTE/TYPE[text()='MULTIPLE_SELECT']])" />
                    <xsl:if test="$number-of-multi-select-elements &gt; 0">
                        <br />
                        <fieldset style="padding:6">
                            <br />
                            <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                <xsl:call-template name="CREATE-MULTI-SEL-TABLE">
                                </xsl:call-template>
                            </table>
                        </fieldset>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:template>

            <xsl:template name="CREATE-ELEMENT">
                <xsl:param name="add-field-text" select="0" />
                <xsl:param name="element-style" select="0" />
                <xsl:param name="recursive-table" select="0" />
                <xsl:param name="actions-section" select="0" />

                <xsl:for-each select="child::*">
                    <xsl:if test="name()='ATTRIBUTE'">
                        <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="SUBTYPE!=''">
                                <xsl:choose>
                                    <xsl:when test="SUBTYPE!='LOOKAHEAD'">
                                        <xsl:if test="$add-field-text = 0">
                                            <xsl:value-of select="FIELD_TEXT" />
                                            &#160;
                                        </xsl:if>
                                        <xsl:element name="{TYPE}">
                                            <xsl:attribute name="TYPE">
                                                <xsl:value-of select="SUBTYPE" />
                                            </xsl:attribute>
                                            <xsl:attribute name="NAME">
                                                <xsl:value-of select="NAME" />
                                            </xsl:attribute>
                                            <xsl:attribute name="TITLE">
                                                <xsl:value-of select="TITLE" />
                                            </xsl:attribute>
                                            <xsl:attribute name="VALUE">
                                                <xsl:value-of select="VALUE" />
                                            </xsl:attribute>
                                            <xsl:attribute name="db_type">
                                                <xsl:value-of select="DB_TYPE" />
                                            </xsl:attribute>
                                            <xsl:attribute name="SIZE">
                                                <xsl:value-of select="SIZE" />
                                            </xsl:attribute>
                                            <xsl:choose>
                                                <xsl:when test="SUBTYPE = 'BUTTON' and $actions-section = 1">
                                                    <xsl:attribute name="CLASS">actionButton</xsl:attribute>
                                                </xsl:when>
                                                <xsl:when test="SUBTYPE = 'BUTTON'">
                                                    <xsl:attribute name="CLASS">fmButton</xsl:attribute>
                                                </xsl:when>
                                            </xsl:choose>
                                            <xsl:attribute name="STYLE">
                                                <xsl:if test="$element-style = 1">
                                                    font-family:Arial;
                                                    font-size:8pt;
                                                </xsl:if>
                                                <xsl:if test="$element-style = 0">
                                                    border-bottom:0px solid;
                                                    border-left:0px solid;
                                                    border-right:0px solid;
                                                    border-top:0px solid;
                                                    font-family:Arial;
                                                    font-size:8pt;
                                                </xsl:if>
                                                <xsl:if test="SUBTYPE = 'CHECKBOX'">
                                                    width:18;
                                                    height:18;
                                                </xsl:if>
                                                <xsl:if test="$add-field-text = 1 and $recursive-table != 1">
                                                    width:120;
                                                </xsl:if>
                                                <xsl:if test="$recursive-table = 1">
                                                    width:
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="SIZE" />
                                                    ;
                                                </xsl:if>
                                            </xsl:attribute>
                                            <xsl:for-each select="EVENTS/*">
                                                <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="." />
                                                </xsl:attribute>
                                            </xsl:for-each>
                                        </xsl:element>
                                    </xsl:when>
                                    <xsl:otherwise>
                                        <SPAN style="font-family:Arial;font-size:8pt;" width="120">
                                            <xsl:element name="{TYPE}">
                                                <xsl:attribute name="TYPE">text</xsl:attribute>
                                                <xsl:attribute name="NAME">
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="NAME" />
                                                </xsl:attribute>
                                                <xsl:attribute name="TITLE">
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="TITLE" />
                                                </xsl:attribute>
                                                <xsl:attribute name="VALUE">
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="VALUE" />
                                                </xsl:attribute>
                                                <xsl:attribute name="db_type">
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="DB_TYPE" />
                                                </xsl:attribute>
                                                <xsl:attribute name="SIZE">
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="SIZE" />
                                                </xsl:attribute>
                                                <xsl:attribute name="bound_data">
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="BOUND_DATA" />
                                                </xsl:attribute>
                                                <xsl:attribute name="STYLE">
                                                    <xsl:if test="$element-style = 1">
                                                        font-family:Arial;
                                                        font-size:8pt;
                                                    </xsl:if>
                                                    <xsl:if test="$element-style = 0">
                                                        border-bottom:0px solid;
                                                        border-left:0px solid;
                                                        border-right:0px solid;
                                                        border-top:0px solid;
                                                        font-family:Arial;
                                                        font-size:8pt;
                                                    </xsl:if>
                                                    <xsl:if test="$add-field-text = 1 and $recursive-table != 1">
                                                        width:105;
                                                    </xsl:if>
                                                    <xsl:if test="$recursive-table = 1">
                                                        width:
                                                        <xsl:value-of select="SIZE" />
                                                        ;
                                                    </xsl:if>
                                                </xsl:attribute>
                                                <xsl:for-each select="EVENTS/*">
                                                    <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
                                                        <xsl:value-of select="." />
                                                    </xsl:attribute>
                                                </xsl:for-each>
                                            </xsl:element>
                                            <img hspace="2"
                                                style="font-family:Arial;font-size:8pt;zoom:100%;cursor:pointer;vertical-align: middle"
                                                onClick="if(get_element('{NAME}').value=='' || get_element('{NAME}').value=='&#60; Mandatory &#62;' || get_element('{NAME}').value=='&#60; M &#62;') get_element('{NAME}').value='%'; get_element('{NAME}').fireEvent('ONCHANGE')"
                                                tabindex="-1"
                                                src="" />
                                        </SPAN>
                                    </xsl:otherwise>
                                </xsl:choose>
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:otherwise>
                                <xsl:if test="$add-field-text = 0">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="FIELD_TEXT" />
                                </xsl:if>
                                <xsl:element name="{TYPE}">
                                    <xsl:if test="TYPE = 'DIV'">
                                        <xsl:attribute name="ID">
                                            <xsl:value-of select="NAME" />
                                        </xsl:attribute>
                                    </xsl:if>
                                    <xsl:if test="TYPE != 'DIV'">
                                        <xsl:attribute name="NAME">
                                            <xsl:value-of select="NAME" />
                                        </xsl:attribute>
                                    </xsl:if>
                                    <xsl:attribute name="TITLE">
                                        <xsl:value-of select="TITLE" />
                                    </xsl:attribute>
                                    <xsl:attribute name="STYLE">
                                        <xsl:if test="$add-field-text = 1 and $recursive-table != 1">
                                            width:120;
                                        </xsl:if>
                                        <xsl:if test="$recursive-table = 1">
                                            width:
                                            <xsl:value-of select="SIZE" />
                                            ;
                                        </xsl:if>
                                        font-family:Arial;
                                        font-size:7pt;
                                        border-bottom:0px solid;
                                        border-left:0px solid;
                                        border-right:0px solid;
                                        border-top:0px solid;
                                    </xsl:attribute>
                                    <xsl:for-each select="EVENTS/*">
                                        <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
                                            <xsl:value-of select="." />
                                        </xsl:attribute>
                                    </xsl:for-each>
                                    <xsl:if test="TYPE='HIDDEN'">
                                        &#160;
                                    </xsl:if>
                                </xsl:element>
                            </xsl:otherwise>
                        </xsl:choose>
                    </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:call-template name="CREATE-ELEMENT" />
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:template>
        </xsl:stylesheet>
    </xml>

    <HEAD>
        <SCRIPT>
            /* FORM LOADED */
            function formLoaded()
            {
                try {
                    create_form();
                }
                catch (errorObject) {
                    var sErrmsg = "Error in JavaScript function formLoaded()";
                    handle_js_error(sErrmsg, errorObject.description);
                }
            }

            // Parse String to XML
            function StringToXML(txt)
            {
                let xml;

                if (window.DOMParser) {
                    // code for Chrome, Firefox, Opera, IE9+, Edge
                    parser = new DOMParser();
                    xml = parser.parseFromString(txt, "text/xml");
                } else {
                    // code for IEs prior to 9
                    xml = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
                    xml.async = false;
                    xml.loadXML(txt);
                };

                return xml;
            };

            function create_form()
            {
                try {
                    if (window.ActiveXObject) {
                        //Version IE
                        document.formDiv.innerHTML = document.all.XMLFormData.transformNode(document.all.XSLDefaultForm);
                    } else {
                        var xmlData = document.getElementById("XMLFormData").innerText;
                        xmlData = StringToXML(xmlData);

                        var xslData = document.getElementById("XSLDefaultForm").innerText;
                        xslData = StringToXML(xslData);

                        //console.log("XML Form Data");
                        //console.log(xmlData);
                        //console.log("XSL Conversion Data");
                        //console.log(xslData);
                        //console.log("New line please");

                        var errors = xmlData.getElementsByTagName('parsererror');
                        if (errors[0].textContent) {
                            var fullErrorText = errors[0].textContent;
                            fullErrorText = fullErrorText.replace("This page contains the following errors:", "")
                            fullErrorText = fullErrorText.replace("Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.", "")
                            console.log(fullErrorText);
                        }

                        //Version ECMA
                        var xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
                        xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xslData);

                        var result = xsltProcessor.transformToDocument(xmlData);

                        console.log(result);
                        if (!result) result = "This was null";

                        //var serializer = new XMLSerializer();
                        //var str = serializer.serializeToString(result);

                        document.getElementById("formDiv").innerHTML = result;
                    }
                } catch (errorObject) {
                    var sErrmsg = "Error has occurred in create_form()";
                    console.log(sErrmsg);
                }
            }

            function handle_js_error(sMsg, sDesc)
            {
                try {
                    //alert(sMsg + "\n\n" + sDesc);
                } catch (errorObject) {
                    var sErrmsg = "Error has occurred in handle_js_error()";
                    handle_js_error(sErrmsg, errorObject.description);
                }
            }
        </SCRIPT>

        <TITLE>XXX</TITLE>
    </HEAD>

    <BODY onLoad="formLoaded()" bgColor="#FFFFFF">
         <DIV id=bigFatDiv>
    <DIV style="text-align: center;">
        <B style="font-family:MS Sans Serif; font-size:8pt;">
            Testing XSLT
        </B>
    </DIV>
    <HR color="red" size="1px">
    </HR>
    <DIV style="text-align: center;">
        <TABLE cellpadding=10 cellspacing=2
            style="border:0; background-Color:#E1EEFF;border-Left:black 1px solid;border-Top:black 1px solid;border-Right:black 1px solid;border-Bottom:black 1px solid;"
            WIDTH=1000>
            <TR>
                <TD>
                    <DIV id="formDiv"></DIV>
                </TD>
            </TR>
        </TABLE>
    </DIV>
</DIV>
    </BODY>
    </HTML>
```

and the result of running the snipped is:

```
error on line 30 at column 34: StartTag: invalid element name
```

Which when investigated is this:

```
                    <SIZE>
```

Completely unsuspicious line. SO maybe someone in the community can point out what im doing wrong or if I should use a different native JS method for XML/XSL trnasformations. Let me know if more details are needed or can helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you shouldn't expect to be able to stuff XML markup into an arbitrary HTML element and then expect to get the XML markup back with `innerText`.

There might be some chance to use a `script` element with e.g. `<script type="application/xslt+xml"></script>` or e.g. `<script type="application/xml"></script>` as the container element and then use the `text` property of the `script` element https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#dom-script-text to get the "script data", e.g. in your case the XML or XSLT markup. But as normal markup in an arbitrary HTML element the HTML parser might have mangled the XML syntax and `innerText` is generated from the mangled content.

```js
    var domParser = new DOMParser();
    var xmlDoc1 = domParser.parseFromString(document.getElementById('xml-input1').text, 'application/xml');
    var sheet1 = domParser.parseFromString(document.getElementById('xslt-code1').text, 'application/xml');
    var processor = new XSLTProcessor();
    processor.importStylesheet(sheet1);
    document.getElementById('xslt-result1').appendChild(processor.transformToFragment(xmlDoc1, document));
```

```css
                  TD.datagridHeader {
                        border-Top: "1 solid buttonhighlight";
                        border-Left: "1 solid buttonhighlight";
                        border-Right: "1 solid buttonshadow";
                        border-Bottom: "1 solid buttonshadow";
                        background-Color: "#C5DEFD";
                        font-family: "MS Sans Serif";
                        font-size: "8pt";
                        padding: "2";
                    }

                    TD.datagridField {
                        border-Top: "1 solid buttonhighlight";
                        border-Left: "1 solid buttonhighlight";
                        border-Right: "1 solid buttonshadow";
                        border-Bottom: "1 solid buttonshadow";
                        background-color: "#FFFFFF";
                        font-size: "8pt";
                        text-align: "RIGHT";
                    }

                    FIELDSET.theStyle {
                        padding: "6";
                        font-family: "MS Sans Serif";
                        font-size: "8pt";
                        width: "1000";
                    }

                    TD.emptyTD {
                        font-family: "MS Sans Serif";
                        font-size: "8pt";
                    }

                    INPUT {
                        font-family: "MS Sans Serif";
                        font-size: "8pt";
                    }

                    INPUT.fmButton {
                        font-family: "MS Sans Serif";
                        font-size: "8pt";
                        background-Color: "#C5DEFD";
                    }

                    INPUT.actionButton {
                        font-family: "MS Sans Serif";
                        font-size: "8pt";
                        background-Color: "#C5DEFD";
                        margin-bottom: "5px";
                    }

                    TD.wingdings {
                        color: white;
                        font-family: "wingdings 2";
                        font-size: 12pt;
                        width: 12;
                    }

                    TD.white {
                        color: white;
                        font-family: MS Sans Serif;
                        font-size: 12pt;
                        width: 12;
                    }

                    SELECT.multiSelect {
                        font-family: MS Sans Serif;
                        font-size: 8pt;
                        width: 180
                    }

                    SELECT {
                        border-top: "1 none buttonhighlight";
                        border-left: "1 none buttonhighlight";
                        border-right: "1 none buttonshadow";
                        border-bottom: "1 none buttonshadow";
                    }
```

```html
<script type="application/xml" id="xml-input1"><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
        <FORM>
            <SECTION title="SuperSection" id="0">
                <NONRECURSIVE>
                    <ELEMENT>
                        <ATTRIBUTE>
                            <TYPE>
                                <![CDATA[IFT]]>
                            </TYPE>
                            <SUBTYPE>
                                <![CDATA[]]>
                            </SUBTYPE>
                            <NAME>
                                <![CDATA[DFLTF]]>
                            </NAME>
                            <DB_TYPE>
                                <![CDATA[V]]>
                            </DB_TYPE>
                            <FIELD_TEXT>
                                <![CDATA[]]>
                            </FIELD_TEXT>
                            <BOUND_DATA>
                                <![CDATA[]]>
                            </BOUND_DATA>
                            <SIZE>
                                <![CDATA[]]>
                            </SIZE>
                            <TITLE>
                                <![CDATA[SOME TEXT]]>
                            </TITLE>
                            <VALUE>
                                <![CDATA[]]>
                            </VALUE>
                            <EVENTS>
                                <![CDATA[]]>
                            </EVENTS>
                        </ATTRIBUTE>
                    </ELEMENT>
                </NONRECURSIVE>
            </SECTION>
        </FORM></script>
    <script type="application/xslt+xml" id="xslt-code1"><xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
            <xsl:output method="html" omit-xml-declaration="yes" standalone="yes" indent="yes" media-type="text/html" />
            <xsl:template match="/FORM/SECTION">
                <xsl:call-template name="CREATE-NORMAL" />
            </xsl:template>

            <xsl:template name="CREATE-NORMAL">
            <fieldset class="theStyle">
                <legend style="font-weight:bold">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@title" />
                </legend>
                <br />
                <xsl:for-each select="child::*">
                    <xsl:if test="name()='NONRECURSIVE'">
                        <xsl:variable name="hidden-elements" select="*[ATTRIBUTE/SUBTYPE[text()='HIDDEN']]" />

                        <xsl:for-each select="$hidden-elements">
                            <xsl:call-template name="CREATE-ELEMENT">
                                <xsl:with-param name="add-field-text" select="1" />
                            </xsl:call-template>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </xsl:if>

                    <xsl:if test="name()='RECURSIVE'">
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </fieldset>

            <xsl:for-each select="child::*">
                <xsl:if test="name()='NONRECURSIVE'">
                    <xsl:variable name="number-of-multi-select-elements"
                        select="count(*[ATTRIBUTE/TYPE[text()='MULTIPLE_SELECT']])" />
                    <xsl:if test="$number-of-multi-select-elements &gt; 0">
                        <br />
                        <fieldset style="padding:6">
                            <br />
                            <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                <xsl:call-template name="CREATE-MULTI-SEL-TABLE">
                                </xsl:call-template>
                            </table>
                        </fieldset>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:template>

            <xsl:template name="CREATE-ELEMENT">
                <xsl:param name="add-field-text" select="0" />
                <xsl:param name="element-style" select="0" />
                <xsl:param name="recursive-table" select="0" />
                <xsl:param name="actions-section" select="0" />

                <xsl:for-each select="child::*">
                    <xsl:if test="name()='ATTRIBUTE'">
                        <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="SUBTYPE!=''">
                                <xsl:choose>
                                    <xsl:when test="SUBTYPE!='LOOKAHEAD'">
                                        <xsl:if test="$add-field-text = 0">
                                            <xsl:value-of select="FIELD_TEXT" />
                                            &#160;
                                        </xsl:if>
                                        <xsl:element name="{TYPE}">
                                            <xsl:attribute name="TYPE">
                                                <xsl:value-of select="SUBTYPE" />
                                            </xsl:attribute>
                                            <xsl:attribute name="NAME">
                                                <xsl:value-of select="NAME" />
                                            </xsl:attribute>
                                            <xsl:attribute name="TITLE">
                                                <xsl:value-of select="TITLE" />
                                            </xsl:attribute>
                                            <xsl:attribute name="VALUE">
                                                <xsl:value-of select="VALUE" />
                                            </xsl:attribute>
                                            <xsl:attribute name="db_type">
                                                <xsl:value-of select="DB_TYPE" />
                                            </xsl:attribute>
                                            <xsl:attribute name="SIZE">
                                                <xsl:value-of select="SIZE" />
                                            </xsl:attribute>
                                            <xsl:choose>
                                                <xsl:when test="SUBTYPE = 'BUTTON' and $actions-section = 1">
                                                    <xsl:attribute name="CLASS">actionButton</xsl:attribute>
                                                </xsl:when>
                                                <xsl:when test="SUBTYPE = 'BUTTON'">
                                                    <xsl:attribute name="CLASS">fmButton</xsl:attribute>
                                                </xsl:when>
                                            </xsl:choose>
                                            <xsl:attribute name="STYLE">
                                                <xsl:if test="$element-style = 1">
                                                    font-family:Arial;
                                                    font-size:8pt;
                                                </xsl:if>
                                                <xsl:if test="$element-style = 0">
                                                    border-bottom:0px solid;
                                                    border-left:0px solid;
                                                    border-right:0px solid;
                                                    border-top:0px solid;
                                                    font-family:Arial;
                                                    font-size:8pt;
                                                </xsl:if>
                                                <xsl:if test="SUBTYPE = 'CHECKBOX'">
                                                    width:18;
                                                    height:18;
                                                </xsl:if>
                                                <xsl:if test="$add-field-text = 1 and $recursive-table != 1">
                                                    width:120;
                                                </xsl:if>
                                                <xsl:if test="$recursive-table = 1">
                                                    width:
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="SIZE" />
                                                    ;
                                                </xsl:if>
                                            </xsl:attribute>
                                            <xsl:for-each select="EVENTS/*">
                                                <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="." />
                                                </xsl:attribute>
                                            </xsl:for-each>
                                        </xsl:element>
                                    </xsl:when>
                                    <xsl:otherwise>
                                        <SPAN style="font-family:Arial;font-size:8pt;" width="120">
                                            <xsl:element name="{TYPE}">
                                                <xsl:attribute name="TYPE">text</xsl:attribute>
                                                <xsl:attribute name="NAME">
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="NAME" />
                                                </xsl:attribute>
                                                <xsl:attribute name="TITLE">
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="TITLE" />
                                                </xsl:attribute>
                                                <xsl:attribute name="VALUE">
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="VALUE" />
                                                </xsl:attribute>
                                                <xsl:attribute name="db_type">
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="DB_TYPE" />
                                                </xsl:attribute>
                                                <xsl:attribute name="SIZE">
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="SIZE" />
                                                </xsl:attribute>
                                                <xsl:attribute name="bound_data">
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="BOUND_DATA" />
                                                </xsl:attribute>
                                                <xsl:attribute name="STYLE">
                                                    <xsl:if test="$element-style = 1">
                                                        font-family:Arial;
                                                        font-size:8pt;
                                                    </xsl:if>
                                                    <xsl:if test="$element-style = 0">
                                                        border-bottom:0px solid;
                                                        border-left:0px solid;
                                                        border-right:0px solid;
                                                        border-top:0px solid;
                                                        font-family:Arial;
                                                        font-size:8pt;
                                                    </xsl:if>
                                                    <xsl:if test="$add-field-text = 1 and $recursive-table != 1">
                                                        width:105;
                                                    </xsl:if>
                                                    <xsl:if test="$recursive-table = 1">
                                                        width:
                                                        <xsl:value-of select="SIZE" />
                                                        ;
                                                    </xsl:if>
                                                </xsl:attribute>
                                                <xsl:for-each select="EVENTS/*">
                                                    <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
                                                        <xsl:value-of select="." />
                                                    </xsl:attribute>
                                                </xsl:for-each>
                                            </xsl:element>
                                            <img hspace="2"
                                                style="font-family:Arial;font-size:8pt;zoom:100%;cursor:pointer;vertical-align: middle"
                                                onClick="if(get_element('{NAME}').value=='' || get_element('{NAME}').value=='&#60; Mandatory &#62;' || get_element('{NAME}').value=='&#60; M &#62;') get_element('{NAME}').value='%'; get_element('{NAME}').fireEvent('ONCHANGE')"
                                                tabindex="-1"
                                                src="" />
                                        </SPAN>
                                    </xsl:otherwise>
                                </xsl:choose>
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:otherwise>
                                <xsl:if test="$add-field-text = 0">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="FIELD_TEXT" />
                                </xsl:if>
                                <xsl:element name="{TYPE}">
                                    <xsl:if test="TYPE = 'DIV'">
                                        <xsl:attribute name="ID">
                                            <xsl:value-of select="NAME" />
                                        </xsl:attribute>
                                    </xsl:if>
                                    <xsl:if test="TYPE != 'DIV'">
                                        <xsl:attribute name="NAME">
                                            <xsl:value-of select="NAME" />
                                        </xsl:attribute>
                                    </xsl:if>
                                    <xsl:attribute name="TITLE">
                                        <xsl:value-of select="TITLE" />
                                    </xsl:attribute>
                                    <xsl:attribute name="STYLE">
                                        <xsl:if test="$add-field-text = 1 and $recursive-table != 1">
                                            width:120;
                                        </xsl:if>
                                        <xsl:if test="$recursive-table = 1">
                                            width:
                                            <xsl:value-of select="SIZE" />
                                            ;
                                        </xsl:if>
                                        font-family:Arial;
                                        font-size:7pt;
                                        border-bottom:0px solid;
                                        border-left:0px solid;
                                        border-right:0px solid;
                                        border-top:0px solid;
                                    </xsl:attribute>
                                    <xsl:for-each select="EVENTS/*">
                                        <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
                                            <xsl:value-of select="." />
                                        </xsl:attribute>
                                    </xsl:for-each>
                                    <xsl:if test="TYPE='HIDDEN'">
                                        &#160;
                                    </xsl:if>
                                </xsl:element>
                            </xsl:otherwise>
                        </xsl:choose>
                    </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:call-template name="CREATE-ELEMENT" />
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:template>
        </xsl:stylesheet></script>
    
 
<div id="xslt-result1"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, will try that. The main annoying bit is that this bit of code works fine in IE... But its IE... Also the elements, still stored as XML inside HTML, were accessed via their IDs like that: document.all.XMLFormData - whish since is deprecated. Maybe though there is a big different between using GetElementById and using .all to access those. WIll report back if I succeed in getting Chrome to render this

Comment: @guesXy, IE had a proprietary extension to HTML called XML data islands but nothing like that exists in HTML5 which all modern browsers follow.

Comment: I see your code works, will now just have to figure out why locally I get null on the transformation, as pretty much doing the same. Once resolved will mark yours as an answer unless there will be any other contribution :)

Comment: Clearly missing something as when I inline all your stuff into one single html document, the transformation returns NULL, as you can try this by saving the below locally as an HTML... Make no sense at the moment. *UPD* cant paste all of here, msg length limited, cant see how to include a snippet in the comment.

Comment: I haven't tested what you posted there but I see you don't use `transformToFragment` as I did so not sure why you expect to be able to create a result document and insert it as a child into an element of another document with your use of `document.getElementById('xslt-result1').appendChild(processor.transformToDocument(xmlDoc1));`

Comment: It was just me playing around with the code, as netither transformToFragment nor *ToDocument works. Still thank you for your time to provide an answer, and point out that data islands are done for :)

Comment: @guesXy, so I put all the stuff from the answer into a single HTML document at https://martin-honnen.github.io/xslt/2021/test2021031001.html and  the XSLT is run from JavaScript without problems in Chrome, Chromium based Edge and Firefox. Not sure where your attempt fails, perhaps start with a working script setup to run a dummy XSLT, then, once that works, fill in the more complex XSLT I would first test outside the browser. If you still have problems, you can raise a new question on that, but try to keep samples to a minimum to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Thanks, I will mark your answer as legit and will go from there! Thank you for your help :)